# calculate the number of weeks in a daterange

Tags: objective-c, date, nsdate

I need to make some time-based statistics over logs that goes on over the course of a year,
all I need to do is the count of the (solar) weeks inside a determined range of dates.

i.e. I need to calculated how many weeks have been occurred between the 1st of Aug 2011 and the 3rd of Sep 2012. and things like this.

I've had the idea of counting the days between the two dates and then divide by 7, but that doesn't count the fact that I could be in between weeks an in this case the value wold not be correct / precise.

Anybody had faced a similar issue before?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you have your two dates in NSDates (date1 and date2). Then call

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
//declare your unitFlags
int unitFlags = NSWeekCalendarUnit;

NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:date1  toDate:date2 options:0];

int weeksInBetween = [dateComponents week];
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I use this code, but Xcode returns a warning. [dateComponents week] seems to be deprecated. Any idea how it works now?

Comment: You can use weekOfYear or weekOfMonth, depending on what you need.

Answer (score 1):

`NSCalendar` is the class that you should take a at into. It allows you to get the `NSDateComponents` from two dates using the [`components:fromDate:toDate:options:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCalendar/components%3afromDate%3atoDate%3aoptions%3a) method, while dealing with all the messed up time stuff for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDateComponents *difference = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay
                                                               fromDate:startDate]
                                                                 toDate:endDate]
                                                                options:0];
NSInteger weeksDiffCount = (((NSInteger)[difference day])/7);
```

Hope it helps.